# Why consumer of Kafka does not receive the records from broker

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My consumer is not getting any records from topic.
Topic is the same for consumer and producer. I can see my topic on the UI of broker.

For consumer I also set the group.id the same as topic name.
I can see in broker UI the messages sent by the producer, but the consumer can not get any records.

And my ConsumerRebalanceListner does not seem to be working. I can't see that it was called.

This is my producer:

```
public class BotKafkaProducer implements Runnable {

    private BotLogger log;
    private Set<NewsLetter> newsLetters;
    private String topicName;
    private Bot bot;
    private News news;

    @Setter
    private NewsDao newsDao;
    @Setter
    private AtomicInteger sentNews;

    private KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer;

    public BotKafkaProducer(BotLogger log, Set<NewsLetter> newsLetters, String topicName,
                            String pathPropKafka, Bot bot, News news) {
        this.log = log;
        this.newsLetters = newsLetters;
        this.topicName = topicName;
        this.bot = bot;
        this.news = news;
        try {
            Properties props = PropertiesHelper.getProperties(pathPropKafka);
            log.info("Success creating Properties for kafka producer.");
            this.kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Error creating Properties for kafka producer.");
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.info("producer start, queue name : " + topicName);
        try {
            log.info("Success creating KafkaProducer .");
            for (NewsLetter newsLetter : newsLetters) {
                String value = new Gson().toJson(newsLetter);
                ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord =
                        new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, value);

                kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord, (recordMetadata, e) -> {
                    // executes every time a record is successfully sent or an exception is thrown
                    if (e == null) {
                        // the record was successfully sent
                        log.info("Received new metadata. \n" +
                                "Topic:" + recordMetadata.topic() + "\n" +
                                "Partition: " + recordMetadata.partition() + "\n" +
                                "Offset: " + recordMetadata.offset() + "\n" +
                                "Timestamp: " + recordMetadata.timestamp());
                    } else {
                        log.error("Error while producing" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                if(sentNews.get()%2000 == 0) {
                    this.kafkaProducer.flush();
                }
                sentNews.getAndIncrement();
            }
            this.kafkaProducer.flush();
            log.info(sentNews.get() + " news letters committed.");
            //update news
            log.info("updating news status...");
            news.setBotStatus(bot.toString(), false);
            log.info(bot.toString() + " set bot status " + news.isBotStatus(bot.toString()));
            newsDao.updateStatus(bot.toString(), news);
            log.info("News status updated for " + bot);
        }catch (Exception e){
            if(kafkaProducer != null)
                this.kafkaProducer.close();
        } finally {
            if(kafkaProducer != null)
                this.kafkaProducer.close(Duration.ofMillis(500));
        }
    }

}
```

this is my consumer:

```
public final class BotKafkaConsumer implements Runnable, ExceptionListener {

    private final BotLogger log;
    private final String topicName;

    private FacebookSender facebookSender;

    private TelegramSender telegramSender;

    private ViberSender viberSender;

    private volatile LocalTime startSendTime;
    private volatile LocalTime endSendTime;
    private AtomicInteger send;
    private AtomicInteger notSend;
    private AtomicInteger producerSent;
    private LocalDateTime startProcess;

    private KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

    private BotKafkaConsumer(Bot bot, BotLogger log, String topicName, String pathPropKafka) {
        this.log = log;
        this.topicName = topicName;
        Properties props;
        try {
            props = PropertiesHelper.getProperties(pathPropKafka);
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-id-" + topicName);
            log.info("Success creating Properties for kafka consumer.");
            this.kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
            this.startSendTime = bot.getStartSendTime();
            this.endSendTime = bot.getEndSendTime();
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Error creating Properties for kafka consumer.");
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public BotKafkaConsumer(Bot bot, BotLogger log, String topicName, String pathPropKafka, Object sender,
                            AtomicInteger send, AtomicInteger notSend, AtomicInteger producerSent, LocalDateTime startProcess){
        this(bot, log, topicName, pathPropKafka);
        this.send = send;
        this.notSend = notSend;
        this.producerSent = producerSent;
        this.startProcess = startProcess;

        if(sender instanceof FacebookSender)
            this.facebookSender = (FacebookSender)sender;
        if(sender instanceof TelegramSender)
            this.telegramSender = (TelegramSender)sender;
        if(sender instanceof ViberSender)
            this.viberSender = (ViberSender)sender;
    }

    public LocalTime getStartSendTime() {
        return startSendTime;
    }

    public LocalTime getEndSendTime() {
        return endSendTime;
    }

    private boolean isNotTimeToSend() {
        return ((startSendTime != null && startSendTime.isAfter(LocalTime.now())) ||
                (endSendTime != null && endSendTime.isBefore(LocalTime.now())));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        // Registering a shutdown hook so we can exit cleanly
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Starting exit...");
            // Note that shutdownhook runs in a separate thread, so the only thing we can safely do to a consumer is wake it up
            this.kafkaConsumer.wakeup();
            try {
                mainThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }));
        try{
            subscribeConsumer();
            if (facebookSender != null) {
                send(this.kafkaConsumer, facebookSender, log);
            } else if (telegramSender != null) {
                send(this.kafkaConsumer, telegramSender, log);
            } else if (viberSender != null) {
                send(this.kafkaConsumer, viberSender, log);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error("BotKafkaConsumer error : " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            log.warn("BotKafkaConsumer closed .");
            if(this.kafkaConsumer != null) {
                this.kafkaConsumer.close(Duration.ofMillis(500));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException e) {
        log.error("consumer : " + this.toString() + " error : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    private void send(KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer, TelegramSender telegramSender, BotLogger log) throws JMSException {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TelegramDto telegramBody = new TelegramDto();
        // Creating inline Keyboard with one button
        InlineKeyboard inlineKeyboard = null;

        synchronized(this) {
            while (true) {
                records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500));
                records.partitions().forEach(tp -> {
                    log.info("Topic : " + tp.topic() + " TP : " + tp.partition());
                });
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    NewsLetter newsLetter = getNewsLetter(record, gson);
                    String id;
                    News news;
                    try {
                        id = newsLetter.getUserId();
                        news = newsLetter.getNews();
                        String text = replaceForTelegram(news.getText());
                        String buttonText = news.getButtonText();
                        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(buttonText)) {
                            String buttonUrl = news.getButtonUrl();
                            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(buttonUrl)) {
                                inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboard().addRow()
                                        .addButton(0, new InlineKeyboardButton(buttonText).setUrl(buttonUrl));
                                telegramBody.setReplyMarkup(inlineKeyboard);
                            }
                        }
                        if (news.getImageUrl() != null) {
                            String imageUrl = "(" + news.getImageUrl() + ")";
                            text = "[\u200B]" + imageUrl + text;
                        }
                        telegramBody.setChatId(id)
                                .setText(text)
                                .setMessageType(TelegramSendType.SEND_MESSAGE);

                        boolean result = telegramSender.sendMessage(telegramBody);
                        processResult(result);
                        log.info("send.get() + notSend.get()" + (send.get() + notSend.get()) +
                                "    producerSent.get()" + producerSent.get());
                        if((send.get() + notSend.get()) >= producerSent.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        log.error(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                if (isNotTimeToSend()) {
                    log.info("is not time to send is : " + isNotTimeToSend());
                    producerSent.set(0);
                    break;
                }
                if((send.get() + notSend.get()) >= producerSent.get()) {
                    LocalDateTime endProcess = LocalDateTime.now();
                    log.info("TELEGRAM PRODUCER TOTAL NEWS are sent : " + producerSent.get() +
                            " by Producer: " + topicName);
                    log.info("TELEGRAM CONSUMER TOTAL NEWS are sent : " + send + ", TOTAL NOT sent : " + notSend +
                            " by Consumer: " + topicName);
                    log.info("START consumerNews process : " + startProcess.toString());
                    log.info("END consumeNews process : " + endProcess.toString());
                    log.info("TOTAL TIME FOR SENDING : " + ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startProcess, endProcess) +
                            " min " + ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(startProcess, endProcess) + " sec " +
                            ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startProcess, endProcess) + " ms");
                    producerSent.set(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void send(KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer, ViberSender viberSender, BotLogger log) throws JMSException {
        // some code of process
    }

    private void send(KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer, FacebookSender facebookSender, BotLogger log) throws JMSException {
    // some code of process
    }


    private void subscribeConsumer() {
//        this.kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName));
        this.kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {
                log.info("Revoke partitions : " + formatPartitions(collection));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {
                collection.forEach(tp -> {
                    long offset = kafkaConsumer.position(tp);
                    log.info("Topic : " + tp.topic() + " Partition : " + tp.partition() +
                            " Offset : " + offset);
                });
                kafkaConsumer.resume(collection);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsLost(Collection<TopicPartition> collection){
                collection.forEach(tp -> {
                    long offset = kafkaConsumer.position(tp);
                    log.info("Topic : " + tp.topic() + " Partition : " + tp.partition() +
                            " Offset : " + offset);
                });
                kafkaConsumer.resume(collection);
            }
        });
    }

    private void processResult(boolean result){
        if (result) {
            send.getAndIncrement();
        } else {
            notSend.getAndIncrement();
        }
    }

    private NewsLetter getNewsLetter(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Gson gson) throws JMSException {
        String text = record.value();
        return gson.fromJson(text, NewsLetter.class);
    }

    private String replaceForTelegram(String text) {
        return text.replace("_", "\\_")
                .replace("`", "\\`")
                .replace("*", "\\*");
    }

    private static List<String> formatPartitions(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        return partitions.stream().map(topicPartition ->
                String.format("topic: %s, partition: %s", topicPartition.topic(), topicPartition.partition()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This is the properties that I use for set up of broker, producer and consumer:

```
# The location of the Kafka server
bootstrap.servers=50-kafka-a:9092
#count of replicas of brokers
replication.factor=3
#max size of message on broker side
#max.message.bytes=10485880
#replica.fetch.max.bytes=10485880
#max size of message on consumer side
#max.partition.fetch.bytes=10485880
broker.id=1
zookeeper.connect=50-kafka-a:2181

##### PRODUCER SETTINGS ######

#to show how many confirmations have to get producer - in our case it is all
acks=all
#it means that two brokers which are async replicas include leader have to answer that they have data
#min.insync.replicas=2
#type of compression message on side of producer
compression.type=snappy
#the count of retry for trying to send message
retries=3
#timeout of producer after that message will be failed
delivery.timeout.ms=120000
#max size of message on the producer side
#max.request.size=10485880
# classes for serializing ...
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer


##### CONSUMER SETTINGS ######

#max size of messages which will be return after calling one call poll()
max.poll.records=1000
# Make Kafka keep track of record reads by the consumer
enable.auto.commit=true
# The time in milliseconds to Kafka write the offset of the last message read
auto.commit.interval.ms=500
#it is need when the start offset is absent or if current offset is not exist more
auto.offset.reset=earliest
#auto.offset.reset=latest
#max size of message on the consumer side
#fetch.max.bytes=10485880
# ... and deserializing messages
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

and dependency is:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please show `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` output for your group id

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the reply, my problem was related to the embedding. I changed the kafka dependency from version 3.4.0 to 1.0.0 and now I can see my client in the kafka interface.
It looks very interesting, but it works.
Unfortunately I can't check the actual version of kafka on the server, and I don't have access to the server to check kafka-consumer-groups --describe via CLI. But now my customer gets 100 notifications, but if the vendor sent 100,000 notifications, he doesn't get them. Why is this happening?

Comment: I would not recommend going to a 5+ year old version of Kafka client. You dont need access to the terminal of the server to run `kafka-consumer-groups` with `--bootstrap-server 50-kafka-a:9092`. Just download Kafka CLI tools locally. Regarding why the code stops - you're calling `break` when the records list is empty.. One empty poll doesn't mean you've consumed to the end of the topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thank you for your reply. Yes, you are right. I can't understand why using unlimited loop in the consumer but now it seems correct I have to use wakeupException in the try/catch of run(), right? And process closing the cosumer in the catch or finally. About versions : i am back to the version 1.0.0 because ConsumerRebalanceListner does not calling in version 3.4.0 and i can not understand why. I thought that it is because version kafka in the server older than in my project and conflict happened. What are you think about?

Comment: I haven't had any such version issues, but I would upgrade to 3.5.1, rather than downgrade two major versions. And you don't need a while loop and manually thread interactions if you used spring-kafka library

Comment: What do you mean, @OneCricketeer ? Can you explane , please?

Comment: You're already using Spring. So use spring-kafka `@KafkaListener` functions rather than define a consumer with a manual loop yourself. Similarly, KafkaTemplate for a producer

Comment: docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#reference

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks for answer, but i am not using Sprinf Boot, it is java project. I upgrated kafka version to 3.4.0 and now it works, but my consumer always poll latest offser of partitions and never reads messages from partiotions. For example : i have topic with 3 partitions - p 1 (low water mark : 987 and high water mark : 993) = 6 msg, p 2 (low water mark : 920 and high water mark : 926) = 6 msg and p 3 (low water mark : 950 and high water mark : 958) = 8 msg and my consumer is getting records from p 1 with offset 994, p 2 with offset 927 and p 3 with offset 959 and they are empty...

Comment: So now you are back to 3.4.0? But you said that didn't work before? You have `@Component` and `@Autowired`, so you are using SpringBoot, or something similar... In any case, check your consumer lag with `kafka-consumer-groups`  CLI script. If there is low/no lag, then your consumer will always read from the end of the topic, yes... You may want to set `enable.auto.commit=false`, btw. Also, check your consumer `isolation.level` setting since Kafka defaults to send transaction markers nowadays, which are "empty records" from a consumer perspective (`read_committed` is not the default)

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer for your help. First of all i done one big mistake - i wrote broker.id=1 in properties for kafka. I think it is the main mistake of work my consumer.  But now i see unstabil working of my consumer- sometimes it works well and sometimes it gets the empty records. Can it happened because i use this consumer for 3 different topic ? May be it has to work only one topic and for others i have to write another class ? Just now my kafka sent twice records to DEV_TELEGRAM topic and get records by consumer and the same time sent records to DEV_VIBER topic and get nothing((

Comment: @OneCricketeer, now my app works next : every 30 min start work thread , that check db   - are there any news for sending or not? If there are - then to begin work producer and sending records to broker. When it was finish - he closes. After producer closing to begin work consumer - creat 3 threads and in this threads consumers run and have to get the records. When consumers done to get records he close too and for next time they start to run after 30 min. The logic is so.

Comment: I suggest creating a new post for any new issues you are seeing. Also, I would recommend using Debezium rather than having your app poll from any database

Answer (score 0):

I am very grateful to @OneCricketeer for his time and support.
The reason of problem was in my kafka properties file. Some property or a group of them were disrupting normal work of kafka consumers.
So now i am using these properties of kafka :

```
# The location of the Kafka server
bootstrap.servers=50-kafka-a:9092

##### PRODUCER SETTINGS ######

#to show how many confirmations have to get producer - in our case it is all
acks=all
# classes for serializing ...
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer


##### CONSUMER SETTINGS ######

#max size of messages which will be return after calling one call poll()
max.poll.records=500
#it is need when the start offset is absent or if current offset is not exist more
auto.offset.reset=latest
# ... and deserializing messages
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```